# Appium: How to terminate webdriver session for mobile automation when test case is having error?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

In mobile automation (Android) using Appium, I realized when a test case is having error the next test case will take a long time to launch. What can I do to increase the automation speed other than decrease the timeout? Is there any way to terminate the session of the error test case once the error has been detected and proceed to run the next test case? Can anyone help me?

Comment: For example if your test case is not able to find an element , it will wait for certain time before move to next step. You can reduce the max wait time for element using webdriver wait. Also if some thing is wrong/failing you can throw exception and catch it at test case level. It will help to move fast on next level.

Comment: Thanks. I also think that this is the alternative for the issue that I have.